# How to Print Embed tag html or content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller, printing

Hi I am using this code for Printing the window content

```
"<html><head><script>function step1(){\n" +
"setTimeout('step2()', 1000);}\n" +
"function step2(){window.print();}\n" +
"</scri" + "pt></head><body onload='step1()'>\n" +
"<object id='PrintId' data='"+source+"' type='application/pdf' style='width:100% !important;height:100% !important'><embed id='PrintId' src='" + source +
"' type='application/pdf' style='width:100% !important;height:100% !important'/></object></body></html>";
```

As same code i am using for to print Images using "Image tag" instead of Object and Embed tag it was working fine but for PDF or Docx,txt file it is not working on any Browser where i am wrong please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On line 2, `setTimeout('step2()'` should be replaced with `setTimeout(step2`, because setTimeout takes the actual function, in this case `step2`. You were giving it a string instead.

Edit: Actually setTimeout can take a string which will be executed once the timer expires so that probably isn't the problem.

Comment: Hi First of all  csp713 thanks for your Qucik Response but i still getting Error. when i click on print icon it is opening new tab of browser and then my file is opening fine but when print function called then print preview is totally empty or if i use CTRL+P it also make Print Preview Empty or Blank But in only Chrome browser there is Print option/Icon i have used it and working fine but why my Print command is not working? 
First i think that before opening the content the Print command running for that i have increase the time but still getting Blank print perview..